# Using DirectX Dinput8.dll directly in C#

Tags: c#, directx

I'm coding and app that requires access to DirectX in C#. Specifically it needs access to Dinput8.dll 's DirectInput8Create function.

I'm actually doing some hooking.. and am currenty just trying to hook the call and pass it through. I am only having issues with finding the correct variable types for the DLL call.

I just had a brainwave and think I will need to use Unsafe to make it work.. but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Your question would be a better one if you provided a little more detail, and showed some code.  What functions do you need in Dinput8.dll?  There might be a canonical way to do what you want in managed code.

Comment: Thanks for that Robert.  I did actually include the function. I also specified that I am doing API hooking. As such I need to be able to at least pass through the variables the application already using the DirectInput8Create function uses.

Comment: So I have tried some unsafe code..

`[DllImport("Dinput8.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,SetLastError =true,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern unsafe int DirectInput8Create(IntPtr hinst, UInt32 dwversion,Guid refid,out void **lpvoid, int* Fail);`
But it's still no joy. Does anybody have an ideas?

Comment: `static unsafe int CreateDevice_Hooked(IntPtr hinst, UInt32 dwversion, Guid refid, out int*[] lpvoid, void* Fail)
        {
            return DirectInput8Create(hinst, dwversion, refid, out lpvoid, Fail);
        }`

Newest version of the code... It works a tad better.. but still freezes the app.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to bump an old post, but for people who are looking for why this hook crashes, it appears as though the hooked function is being called from within the hook. This creates an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you went straight into hooking... So I might be missing something due the vagueness of the question.

If you want to hook DirectX from c# that's one thing...
But if you just want real access to the DX,Direct Input then I'd just use [SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/)...

I've used it before, specifically with Direct Input to get direct access to an Xbox controller connected to a windows PC and the experience was perfectly friction-less.

Comment: #DX doesn't support DX8, unfortunately, at this point they have experimental support for DX9.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I don't know why you seem to think so.. I'm staring at the code right now: http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Source/SharpDX.DirectInput/DirectInput.cs It's pretty clear that he is calling the Dinput8.dll... e.g.: DInput.DirectInput8Create etc.

Comment: Hmmm... Then their landing page is out of date :).

Comment: Yeah.. so I am hooking.. This is for Extending an application we are already using. I need to be able to catch it setting up Dinput. Mainly so I can get the pointers from the Vtables. We are ultimately trying to catch GetDeviceStatus so we can add custom input from another device we are pulling readings from.. It's a long story and we would write a driver if we though that would work, but it wont. So we are trying to 'cheat' the system and insert the info directly.

Comment: You can use EasyHook to hook native API from .NET/C#: http://easyhook.codeplex.com/